# sorting json array by value in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of json as shown below and i want to sort it by size

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"file_name":"Desert - Copy.jpg","content_type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/mywebsite.com\/public_html\/www\/tmp\/0000000012","sha256":"010f60d2927a35d0235490136ef9f4953b7ee453073794bcaf153d20a64544ea","size":"845941"}
    [1] => {"file_name":"Hydrangeas - Copy.jpg","content_type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/mywebsite.com\/public_html\/www\/tmp\/0000000013","sha256":"3b92fede080f9b0ec902afc58831191b5b8ccbaf6732352fd7a8b445d1e9f0bd","size":"595284"}
    [2] => {"file_name":"Tulips.jpg","content_type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/mywebsite.com\/public_html\/www\/tmp\/0000000014","sha256":"b9352f2565260219db72fc1fc896113a26c85866b69c50d3970c4d9f5cce830a","size":"620888"}
)
```

Result expected:

```
Array
(

    [0] => {"file_name":"Hydrangeas - Copy.jpg","content_type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/mywebsite.com\/public_html\/www\/tmp\/0000000013","sha256":"3b92fede080f9b0ec902afc58831191b5b8ccbaf6732352fd7a8b445d1e9f0bd","size":"595284"}
    [1] => {"file_name":"Tulips.jpg","content_type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/mywebsite.com\/public_html\/www\/tmp\/0000000014","sha256":"b9352f2565260219db72fc1fc896113a26c85866b69c50d3970c4d9f5cce830a","size":"620888"}
    [2] => {"file_name":"Desert - Copy.jpg","content_type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/mywebsite.com\/public_html\/www\/tmp\/0000000012","sha256":"010f60d2927a35d0235490136ef9f4953b7ee453073794bcaf153d20a64544ea","size":"845941"}
)
```

How do i accomplish this in an efficient manner

Comment: convert to array and use `array_multisort()` http://stackoverflow.com/a/96870/6797531

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 function sortByYear($a, $b) {
 $dA = new DateTime($a['date']);
 $dB = new DateTime($b['date']);
return $dA->format('y') - $dB->format('y');
 }
$data = '{"info":[{"id":1, "title":"original title", "name":"john doe", "date":"2010-05-15"}, {"id":2, "title":"another title", "name":"foo bar", "date":"2009-04-11"}]}';
$d = json_decode($data, true);
$info = $d['info'];
usort($info, 'sortByYear');

print_r($info);
?>
```

**source:**http://codepad.org/6N4fmbKG

You should read this for further help:[How to sort a JSON array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808783/how-to-sort-a-json-array-with-php)

Comment: This answer is a copy/paste from a sort-of similar SO question, and apart from pointing to `usort()` it doesn't help the OP at all.

Comment: Hey. I had posted the code because SO does not encourage users to post link only answers. As links can be dead after some time. And respecting the original question source i have provided the link to the source and the similiar question. :)

Comment: If you think this question is the same as the one you linked to (and so deserves an identical answer) then it should be closed as a duplicate, rather than copying the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i came up with but i welcome more efficient solutions

```
function sort_json($json_array)
    {
        if (count($json_array) > 1) {
            //convert to array
            foreach ($json_array as &$json) {
                $array[] = json_decode($json);

            }
            // sort in ascending order by size
            usort($array, function($a, $b)
            {
                return $a->size < $b->size ? -1 : 1; //Compare the sizes
            });

            //convert back to json
            $json_array = array();
            foreach ($array as &$a) {
                $json_array[] = json_encode($a);
            }
        }
        return $json_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code:**

```
function sortBySize($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a['size'] == $b['size']) return 0;
        return ($a['size'] < $b['size']) ? -1 : 1;

    }

usort($data, "sortBySize");
```

**How usort wor**k : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_usort.asp