# how to sort array of object in asc or desc order

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have an array of object which created manually by be and I need to sort it in desc or asc order based on date.
First I have make it a collection, using collect function in php laravel.
I already tried sortBy and sortby desc but it does not work:

```
[
  {
    "id": 22,
    "date": "2022-03-24",
    "form_name": "cashbook",
    "description": "sed<br>asdas",
    "credit": 90,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 90
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "date": "2022-03-23",
    "form_name": "cashbook",
    "description": "sed<br>Check the To Do List Task if task due date/time is passed",
    "credit": 700,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 790
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "date": "2022-03-24",
    "form_name": "cashbook",
    "description": "sed<br>نقد رقم",
    "credit": 700,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 1490
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "date": "2022-03-24",
    "form_name": "cashbook",
    "description": "sed<br>نقد رقم",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 700,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 790
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "date": "2022-03-24",
    "form_name": "cashbook",
    "description": "sed<br>نقد رقم",
    "credit": 700,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 1490
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "date": "2022-03-21",
    "form_name": "advance",
    "description": "sed<br>2000",
    "credit": 9090,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 10580
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "date": "2022-03-21",
    "form_name": "advance",
    "description": "sed<br>2000",
    "credit": 9090,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 19670
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "شلجم--توڑا--4<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--2532 LAS",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": -44,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 19626
  },
  {
    "id": 99,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--3<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>9--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--2532 LAS",
    "credit": 335,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 19961
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--3<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>9--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--2532 LAS",
    "credit": 335,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 20296
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>90--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--2532 LAS",
    "credit": 18711,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 39007
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>90--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--2532 LAS",
    "credit": 18891,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 57898
  },
  {
    "id": 103,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>شلجم--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>90--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--2532 LAS",
    "credit": 9459,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 67357
  },
  {
    "id": 104,
    "date": "2022-03-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>شلجم--توڑا--50<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>90--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--abc",
    "credit": 5157,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 72514
  },
  {
    "id": 105,
    "date": "2022-03-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>شلجم--توڑا--50<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>90--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--abc123",
    "credit": 5355,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 77869
  },
  {
    "id": 106,
    "date": "2022-03-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>90",
    "credit": 18891,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 96760
  },
  {
    "id": 107,
    "date": "2022-03-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "کدو--توڑا--50<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23",
    "credit": 6442,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 103202
  },
  {
    "id": 108,
    "date": "2022-03-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--پیٹی--4<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23",
    "credit": 155,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 103357
  },
  {
    "id": 109,
    "date": "2022-04-02",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>90--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--90",
    "credit": 18508,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 121865
  },
  {
    "id": 110,
    "date": "2022-04-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>180",
    "credit": 27292,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 149157
  },
  {
    "id": 116,
    "date": "2022-04-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23--@lang(\"dashboard.vehicle_number\")--mns-123",
    "credit": 11595,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 160752
  },
  {
    "id": 117,
    "date": "2022-04-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23",
    "credit": 11595,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 172347
  },
  {
    "id": 119,
    "date": "2022-04-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--90<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": -7455,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 164892
  },
  {
    "id": 120,
    "date": "2022-07-21",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--من--100<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>50",
    "credit": 384,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 165276
  },
  {
    "id": 121,
    "date": "2022-07-22",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--من--50<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>150",
    "credit": 219,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 165495
  },
  {
    "id": 124,
    "date": "2022-07-22",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--من--80<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>120",
    "credit": 492,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 165987
  },
  {
    "id": 127,
    "date": "2022-07-22",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "sed<br>کدو--توڑا--50<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>100",
    "credit": 11100,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 177087
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.buyer\")--jkj",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 177177
  },
  {
    "id": 108,
    "date": "2022-03-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.buyer\")--مزدوری",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 177267
  },
  {
    "id": 108,
    "date": "2022-03-28",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.buyer\")--sdsa",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 177357
  },
  {
    "id": 109,
    "date": "2022-04-02",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.buyer\")--opop",
    "credit": "9090",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 186447
  },
  {
    "id": 109,
    "date": "2022-04-02",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.buyer\")--dsadsa",
    "credit": "9099",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 195546
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "date": "2022-03-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.seller\")--mll",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 195636
  },
  {
    "id": 110,
    "date": "2022-04-25",
    "form_name": "purchase",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.seller\")--مزدوری",
    "credit": "500",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 196136
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "date": "2022-01-10",
    "form_name": "supplies",
    "description": "12<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23--توڑا",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 2072,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 194064
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "date": "2022-02-22",
    "form_name": "supplies",
    "description": "1<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>23--توڑا",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 87,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 193977
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "date": "2022-02-22",
    "form_name": "supplies",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.expense_by_customer\")--مزدوری",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 32,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 193945
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "date": "2022-04-02",
    "form_name": "loot",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.expensebycustomer\")--rent",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 194035
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "date": "2022-04-02",
    "form_name": "loot",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.expensebycustomer\")--mlklkl",
    "credit": "9090",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 203125
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "date": "2022-04-02",
    "form_name": "loot",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.expensebycustomer\")--jkjkjk",
    "credit": "9090",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 212215
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "date": "2022-05-10",
    "form_name": "loading",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.advance_payment\")--مزدوری",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 212305
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "date": "2022-05-10",
    "form_name": "loading",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.advance_payment\")--rent",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 212395
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2022-05-17",
    "form_name": "sale",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.add-lootWiseSales\")---کدو--1<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>121<br>کدو--1<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>122<br>",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": "226",
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 212169
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "date": "2022-05-24",
    "form_name": "sale",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.add-productWiseSales\")---کدو--4<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>4<br>شلجم--2<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>2<br>",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": "542",
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 211627
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "date": "2022-05-24",
    "form_name": "sale",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.add-productWiseSales\")---کدو--1<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>1<br>شلجم--1<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>1<br>",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": "188",
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 211439
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "date": "2022-05-24",
    "form_name": "sale",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.add-productWiseSales\")---کدو--4<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>4<br>شلجم--0<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>0<br>",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": "433",
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 211006
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "date": "2022-05-26",
    "form_name": "sale",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.add-productWiseSales\")---کدو--1<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>1<br>شلجم--1<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>1<br>",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": "231",
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 210775
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "date": "2022-07-05",
    "form_name": "productIn",
    "description": "asa--شاپر--abc--",
    "credit": 650,
    "debit": 650,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 210775
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "date": "2022-07-26",
    "form_name": "productIn",
    "description": "شلجم--شاپر--sdsa--کدو--شاپر--jkjjkjk--",
    "credit": 8100,
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 218875
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "date": "2022-07-26",
    "form_name": "productIn",
    "description": "@lang(\"dashboard.expensebycustomer\")--asas",
    "credit": "90",
    "debit": 0,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 218965
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "date": "2022-07-05",
    "form_name": "productInSale",
    "description": "asa--شاپر--شاپر--4<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>12121",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 54350,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 164615
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "date": "2022-07-13",
    "form_name": "productInSale",
    "description": "مٹر--شاپر--شاپر--20<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>500",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 10240,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 154375
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "date": "2022-07-26",
    "form_name": "productInSale",
    "description": "شلجم--شاپر--شاپر--10<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>300",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 3080,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 151295
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "date": "2022-07-26",
    "form_name": "productInSale",
    "description": "کدو--شاپر--شاپر--5<span class=\"backslash\">/</span>1000",
    "credit": 0,
    "debit": 5275,
    "status": 1,
    "balance": 146020
  }
]
```

here is my array of object.

Comment: I helped a little, but you should read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Where are your Laravel codes?

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = array_column($your_array_of_object, 'column name base on for sorting like date etc');
array_multisort($date, SORT_DESC, $your array of object);
```

this is worked at my side

Answer (score 1):

This should help: [How to sort a JSON array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808783/how-to-sort-a-json-array-with-php)

Below, $jsonArray is your array of JSON objects.

```
$data = json_decode($jsonArray, false);
        
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->id <=> $b->id
});
```

Learn more about usort: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Learn more about spaceship operator: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_spaceship_operator.htm

Edits suggested by Timo have been made to this post!

Comment: This code snippet will not work; By passing `true` as second parameter to [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the outcome is an associative array, but in the comparison function you use it as a (a sort of) object. I suggest changing the decoding call to `$data = json_decode($jsonArray, false);` and change the comparison to valid PHP `return $a->id <=> $b->id`.